# What is the correct way to deploy a class as a Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, payment-gateway, paytm

I want to expose a class as a Firebase Cloud Function. Below is my index.js:

```
"use strict";

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

var crypto = require('crypto');

class PaytmChecksum {

    static encrypt(input, key) {
        var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('AES-128-CBC', key, PaytmChecksum.iv);
        var encrypted = cipher.update(input, 'binary', 'base64');
        encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
        return encrypted;
    }
    static decrypt(encrypted, key) {
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-128-CBC', key, PaytmChecksum.iv);
        var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'binary');
        try {
            decrypted += decipher.final('binary');
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
    static generateSignature(params, key) {
        if (typeof params !== "object" && typeof params !== "string") {
            var error = "string or object expected, " + (typeof params) + " given.";
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        if (typeof params !== "string"){
            params = PaytmChecksum.getStringByParams(params);
        }
        return PaytmChecksum.generateSignatureByString(params, key);
    }


    static verifySignature(params, key, checksum) {
        if (typeof params !== "object" && typeof params !== "string") {
            var error = "string or object expected, " + (typeof params) + " given.";
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        if(params.hasOwnProperty("CHECKSUMHASH")){
            delete params.CHECKSUMHASH
        }
        if (typeof params !== "string"){
            params = PaytmChecksum.getStringByParams(params);
        }
        return PaytmChecksum.verifySignatureByString(params, key, checksum);
    }

    static async generateSignatureByString(params, key) {
        var salt = await PaytmChecksum.generateRandomString(4);
        return PaytmChecksum.calculateChecksum(params, key, salt);
    }

    static verifySignatureByString(params, key, checksum) {
        var paytm_hash = PaytmChecksum.decrypt(checksum, key);
        var salt = paytm_hash.substr(paytm_hash.length - 4);
        return (paytm_hash === PaytmChecksum.calculateHash(params, salt));
    }

    static generateRandomString(length) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes((length * 3.0) / 4.0, (err, buf) => {
                if (!err) {
                    var salt = buf.toString("base64");
                    resolve(salt);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("error occurred in generateRandomString: " + err);
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    static getStringByParams(params) {
        var data = {};
        Object.keys(params).sort().forEach((key,value) => {
            data[key] = (params[key] !== null && params[key].toLowerCase() !== "null") ? params[key] : "";
        });
        return Object.values(data).join('|');
    }

    static calculateHash(params, salt) {
        var finalString = params + "|" + salt;
        return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(finalString).digest('hex') + salt;
    }
    static calculateChecksum(params, key, salt) {
        var hashString = PaytmChecksum.calculateHash(params, salt);
        return PaytmChecksum.encrypt(hashString,key);
    }
}
PaytmChecksum.iv = '@@@@&&&&####$$$$';
modules.exports = PaytmChecksum;
```

When I deployed this function, it says deployed successfully, but I don't see the function in Firebase console. Below is the output of deploy command:

```
sr@SR:~/AndroidStudioProjects/BuddayWale/functions$ sudo firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'buddaywale-b1923'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /home/sr/AndroidStudioProjects/BuddayWale/functions
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...

⚠  functions: The Node.js 8 runtime is deprecated and will be decommissioned on 2021-03-15. For more information, see: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-runtime

✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/buddaywale-b1923/overview
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to deploy cloud function?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use express.js framework

Here is the example

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
class PaytmChecksum{
//code
}
class PaytmChecksum1{
//code
}
app.post('/name',(req,res)=>{
   let paymentChecksum = new PaytmChecksum();
   let result = paymentChecksum. //your method
   res.send(result);
})
app.post('/another/name',(req,res)=>{
   let paymentChecksum1 = new PaytmChecksum1();
   let result = paymentChecksum1. //your method
   res.send(result);
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Here is the Docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Comment: Good one!  ---

Answer (score 0):

While you can use classes such as the one in your Cloud Functions code, in order for Firebase to be able to wire up your functions, they must be declared as `functions.` and then then type of trigger.

I don't at first glance see any Cloud Functions declaration ( `exports.helloWorld = functions.... => {` in the code you shared, so that would explain why you don't see anything of this code show up in the Cloud Functions console.

A simple way to use your class in a Cloud Function could be:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  let paymentChecksum = new PaytmChecksum();
  let result = paymentChecksum.encrypt("...", "...")
  response.send(result);
});
```

For more on this, including the various ways in which your code can be triggered, see the link to the documentation in your code: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

Comment: Hey Puf, thank you so much for responding. I have a concern here. What if I want to use the class in my code? As you see there are many functions in my class. 'helloWorld' here would only enable me to use the 'encrypt' function of the class. What if I wish to use other functions too? Will I have to export all the other functions too then? Isn't there a way that I can implement it in such a way that I can be able to use the functions as PaytmChecksum.generateSignature() or PaytmChecksum.verifySignature() directly in my android code? Would really appreciate your help Puf!

Comment: You'll have to export each function in the class that you want to call/trigger externally. You could probably write come code to generate the exports automatically. But it'd be quite involved.